# python Pandas calling a complex function in groupby.agg

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

```
Below is my dataframe

    Txn_Key Send_Agent           Send_Time            Pay_Time  Send_Amount  \
0         NaN  ANO080012 2012-05-31 02:25:00 2012-05-31 21:43:00       490.00
1         NaN  AUK359401 2012-05-31 11:25:00 2012-05-31 11:57:00       616.16
2         NaN  ACL000105 2012-05-31 13:07:00 2012-05-31 17:36:00       193.78
3         NaN  AED420319 2012-05-31 10:50:00 2012-05-31 11:34:00       999.43
4         NaN  ARA030210 2012-05-30 12:14:00 2012-05-31 04:16:00       433.29
5         NaN  AJ5020114 2012-05-31 02:37:00 2012-05-31 04:31:00       378.00
6         NaN  A11171047 2012-05-31 09:39:00 2012-05-31 10:08:00       865.34
  Pay_Amount        MTCN      Send_Phone  Refund_Flag       time_diff
0         475.68  9323625903        97549829          NaN 0 days 19:18:00
1         600.87  3545067820    440000000000          NaN 0 days 00:32:00
2         185.21  1453132764            0511          NaN 0 days 04:29:00
3         963.04  4509062067    971566016900          NaN 0 days 00:44:00
4         423.75  6898279087             144          NaN 0 days 16:02:00
5         377.99  5170985243    963954932506          NaN 0 days 01:54:00
6         833.89  5352719100      0644798854          NaN 0 days 00:29:00
```

So , I need a count when Send_Amount is same for the next row. A groupby apply using a lambda works perfectly fine:

```
txn1 = txns.loc[:,['Send_Agent','Send_Amount']]
 Send_repeat_count =  txn1.groupby('Send_Agent').apply(lambda txn1 : (txn1.Send_Amount.shift() == txn1.Send_Amount).cumsum()
```

....: )

But a similar lambda function did not work in groupby.agg .

```
grouped=txn.groupby('Send_Agent')

x=grouped.agg({'Send_Amount':'mean','Pay_Amount':'mean','time_diff':'min','MTCN':'size','Send_Phone':'nunique','Refund_Flag':'count','Send_Amount':'lambda txn1 : (txn1.Send_Amount.shift() == txn1.Send_Amount).cumsum()'})

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'Send_Amount'
```

So , I wrote a separate function to do the same and called it in my groupby.agg

```
 def repeat_count(x):
if x==x.shift():
 ....:         cumsum()


x = grouped.agg({'Send_Amount':'mean','Pay_Amount':'mean','time_diff':'min','MTCN':'size','Send_Phone':'nunique','Refund_Flag':'count','Send_Amount':repeat_count(x)})

     ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

If cumsum can work fine with group by.apply why it does not work inside a function.

Comment: Consider at an example where `Send_Agent` has duplicate values. Then `cumsum()` will return a Series with more than one row. `groupby/apply` works because it will concatenate the Series into a DataFrame. `groupby/agg` fails because the value returned by the `agg` function must be a scalar, not a Series. It is not clear how to fix the problem because it is not clear what result you would want returned when the `Send_Agent` column contains duplicate values.

Comment: If thats the case then I guess groupby.apply is a good way. But what if I store  that count of cumsum()  along with that Send_Amount only when it exists. Is that something attainable by using groupby.agg? Groupby.apply is applying to each row of the dataframe and also returning value of cumsum() as 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the `Send_Agent` column is going to contain duplicates (otherwise, there would be no point in grouping by `Send_Agent`). Moreover, `(x==x.shift()).cumsum()` will return a Series with as many rows as there are duplicates in each `Send_Agent` group.

`df.groupby(...).agg(func)` requires that `func` return a scalar (such as a float). `func` is not allowed to return a Series. (In contrast, `func` can return a `Series` or even `DataFrame` when `df.groupby(...).apply(func)` is used.)

---

If you want to count the number of adjacent rows in a group which are equal you could use `sum()` instead of `cumsum()`. For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.width = 1000
nan = np.nan
txn = pd.DataFrame(
    {'MTCN': [0, 9323625903, 3545067820, 1453132764, 4509062067, 6898279087, 5170985243, 5352719100], 
     'Pay_Amount': [1, 475.68, 600.87, 185.21, 963.04, 423.75, 377.99, 833.89],
     'Pay_Time': ['2012-05-31 10:08:00', '2012-05-31 21:43:00', '2012-05-31 11:57:00', '2012-05-31 17:36:00', 
                  '2012-05-31 11:34:00', '2012-05-31 04:16:00', '2012-05-31 04:31:00', 
                  '2012-05-31 10:08:00'], 
     'Refund_Flag': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 
     'Send_Amount': [865.34, 490.0, 616.16, 193.78, 999.43, 433.29, 378.0, 865.34],
     'Send_Phone': [3, 97549829, 440000000000, 511, 971566016900, 144, 963954932506, 644798854],
     'Send_Time': ['2012-05-31 09:39:00', '2012-05-31 02:25:00', '2012-05-31 11:25:00', '2012-05-31 13:07:00', 
                   '2012-05-31 10:50:00', '2012-05-30 12:14:00', '2012-05-31 02:37:00', 
                   '2012-05-31 09:39:00'], 
     'Txn_Key': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
     'Send_Agent': ['A11171047', 'ANO080012', 'AUK359401', 'ACL000105', 'AED420319', 
                    'ARA030210', 'AJ5020114', 'A11171047'], 
     'time_diff': ['0 days 00:29:00', '0 days 19:18:00', '0 days 00:32:00', '0 days 04:29:00', 
                   '0 days 00:44:00', '0 days 16:02:00', '0 days 01:54:00', 
                   '0 days 00:29:00', ]} )
txn['time_diff'] = pd.to_timedelta(txn['time_diff']) 

grouped = txn.groupby('Send_Agent')

def repeat_count(s):
    return (s.shift() == s).sum()

result = grouped.agg(
    {'Pay_Amount':'mean',
     'time_diff':'min',
     'MTCN':'size',
     'Send_Phone':'nunique',
     'Refund_Flag':'count',
     'Send_Amount': ['mean', repeat_count]})
print(result)
```

yields

```
           Refund_Flag       time_diff Send_Phone MTCN Send_Amount              Pay_Amount
                 count             min    nunique size        mean repeat_count       mean
Send_Agent                                                                                
A11171047            0   1740000000000          2    2      865.34          1.0    417.445
ACL000105            0  16140000000000          1    1      193.78          0.0    185.210
AED420319            0   2640000000000          1    1      999.43          0.0    963.040
AJ5020114            0   6840000000000          1    1      378.00          0.0    377.990
ANO080012            0  69480000000000          1    1      490.00          0.0    475.680
ARA030210            0  57720000000000          1    1      433.29          0.0    423.750
AUK359401            0   1920000000000          1    1      616.16          0.0    600.870
```

(I added an extra row so that `repeat_count` does not always return 0.)

---

When you use `DataFrame.groupby(...).apply(func)`, the objects passed to `func` are DataFrames. Thus,

```
txn1.groupby('Send_Agent').apply(
    lambda txn1 : (txn1.Send_Amount.shift() == txn1.Send_Amount).cumsum())
```

works because the `txn1` inside the `lambda` is a DataFrame with a `Send_Amount` column.

---

In contrast, when you use `DataFrame.groupby(...).agg({'col': func})`, the objects passed to `func` are Series with values from the column specified by `col`. Thus

```
x = grouped.agg({'Send_Amount':'mean','Pay_Amount':'mean','time_diff':'min','MTCN':'size','Send_Phone':'nunique','Refund_Flag':'count','Send_Amount':lambda txn1 : (txn1.Send_Amount.shift() == txn1.Send_Amount).cumsum()})
```

raised `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'Send_Amount'` because the Series passed to the `lambda` function (and bound to the variable `txn1`) has no `Send_Amount` attribute.

---

If you use something like `repeat_count`:

```
def repeat_count(x):
    if x==x.shift():
        return x.cumsum()
```

then `if x==x.shift()` raises

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

because `x==x.shift()` is a Series and `if expression` causes `expression` to be evaluated in a boolean context. That is, `expression.__bool__()` gets called. `__bool__` must return either True or False or raise an exception. Thus, for `if x==x.shift()` to make sense, `(x==x.shift()).__bool__()` would have to return either True or False.

`Series.__bool__()` always raises the `ValueError` above because Pandas (by design) does not guess if it should return True when *all* the values in the Series are True or when *any* of the values are True, or when the Series is merely nonempty, etc....  The `ValueError` message points you in the right direction. Usually the problem is solved by being explicit about what boolean value you want by calling `(x==x.shift()).any()` or `(x==x.shift()).all()`, etc.

---

A note on performance: Generally, using `groupby/agg` with a custom function does not perform as well as `groupby/agg` with a built-in method like `count` or `sum`. So it usually pays to figure out a way (if possible) to express the calculation in terms of built-in methods. In this case, you could do a preparatory calculation *on the whole DataFrame* which would then allow you to use `groupby/agg/sum`:

```
txn = txn.sort_values(by='Send_Agent')
txn['repeat'] = ((txn['Send_Agent'].shift() == txn['Send_Agent']) 
                 & (txn['Send_Agent'].shift() == txn['Send_Agent']))

grouped = txn.groupby('Send_Agent')
result = grouped.agg(
    {'Pay_Amount':'mean',
     'time_diff':'min',
     'MTCN':'size',
     'Send_Phone':'nunique',
     'Refund_Flag':'count',
     'Send_Amount': 'mean',
     'repeat':'sum'})
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for a detailed explanation.